# How to stop the loop after one try?

Tags: c, function, loops

I am facing some problem here. Whenever I run this code it asks me about **name and date of birth**. When I give it, it asks me again until I press Ctrl+D. I want this process to be stop after one time and instead it asks me, do you want to continue? If I say yes then it repeat the loop and again ask me one more time. How to do this? I tried but failed.

```
int main(void){
    const char *listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth"};
    char data[2][51];
    int done = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "w+");
    while (!done){
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]) != 1){
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!done){
            fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", data[0], data[1]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think the while loop does?

Comment: I want this to not repeat the process of asking me again name and date of birth and stop itself and ask for permission to continue again.

Comment: for this kind of work, it's better to use do-while loop, which runs once even the predicate is false or true.

Comment: Just remove the while loop. The question was not intended to be answered, but to be pondered upon

Comment: The return value coming from `scanf` is the count of parameters that have been successfully scanned in and formatted.  Your `scanf` function scans in exactly one parameter, and if it is formatted properly, then the function will return one (1).  See answer below for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your post correctly, after the *first* prompt for name and [then] DOB, you want to inject a "Shall I continue?" question.

Here's the refactored code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
domore(void)
{
    char buf[51];
    int moreflg = -1;

    while (moreflg < 0) {
        printf("Shall I continue (y/n)? ");
        if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", buf) != 1)
            break;

        switch (buf[0]) {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
            moreflg = 1;
            break;

        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            moreflg = 0;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (moreflg < 0)
        moreflg = 0;

    return moreflg;
}

int
main(void)
{
    const char *listing[] = { "Name", "Date of birth" };
    char data[2][51];
    int done = 0;
    int again = 0;
    FILE *fp;

#if 0
    fp = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "w+");
#else
    fp = fopen("/tmp/file.txt", "w+");
#endif

    while (!done) {
        if (again) {
            if (! domore())
                break;
        }
        again = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]) != 1) {
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!done) {
            fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", data[0], data[1]);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro but it didn't store in text file.

Comment: I tested this and, here, it did store. So, if you're getting _no_ output, I'm a bit confused. Opening with `w+`, opens the file for R/W, but, it _truncates_ on each program invocation. So, if you run the program once, store [say] two entries, these can be displayed with (e.g.) `cat`. If you invoke the program a _second_ time, and store a single new entry, the file will _only_ have this last entry. If you wish to add/append [and _not_ clear] on multiple invocations, I'd use `a+` instead. If there's more to your program (i.e. trying to read back later, you may need an `fseek` to rewind the file)

Answer (score 1):

[scanf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm) returns the count of parameters successfully matched and formatted,  or EOF (-1) in case of an invalid input.

So, the expressions,

```
char data[1][50]={0};
int val=0;

int count = scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[0]); // 1 parameter to scan and format
```

will return 1, for a single formatted item.

To get more than 1, you have to scan in, and successfully format more than one item:

```
count = scanf(" %50[^\n] %d", data[0], &val); //2 parameters to scan and format.
```

(The return value here will be `2` if successful.)

So, if you change your loop exit criteria to match these expectations, your loop will exit properly.

```
if (scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]) == 1){//now 'done' will be set to true (1)
                                ^^
```

***Edit***:  Illustrates concepts described above:
(Note, uncomment your file functions, I did not need them for this illustration.)

Program loops until both 'name' and 'date of birth' are captured into a 2D character array.  Loop exit criteria uses count of successful, single parameter scanf calls:

```
int main(void){
    const char *listing[] = {"Name", "Date of birth"};
    char data[2][51];
    int done = 0;
    int count = 0;//added to allow visibility of return value of scanf function.
    FILE *fp;

    //fp = fopen("/home/bilal/Documents/file.txt", "w+");
    while (done != 2){
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            count = scanf(" %50[^\n]", data[i]);
            if (count != EOF){
                done += count;
                // 'break' is not needed here, let the loop leave naturally
            }
        }
    }
    if (done == 2)//moved outside of loop because both variables
    {             //need to be populated before printing
        ;//fprintf(fp, "%s %s\n", data[0], data[1]);
    }

    //fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am not getting what are you talking about?

Comment: Does that mean you are not getting the same results, or that you do not understand what I am saying?

Comment: @NatashaBibi -  I will edit in an example of your code modified to use  what I have talked about...

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` function returns the number of input items success‐fully matched and assigned. So when you type something from the keyboard, the return value of this function is always `1` in your case (you try to input the string, then every character from the keyboard is added to your string).

You can use `fgets` then compare with the string that content only the enter character "\n" when you want to quit the loop.

```
            printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
            if (strcmp(fgets(data[i], 51, stdin), "\n") == 0){
                done = 1;
                break;
            }
```

With this code, if you want to quit the `while` loop, you just have to hit only ENTER.

Comment: Sorry bro, this code is not working. I just to want to stop the loop so that it allow me to enter one time not multiple times. And instead ask me for permission to start again asking me.

Comment: @NatashaBibi if you need just one time, you just delete the while loop. It's enough